Same entity in different pages even sorting by Id
I'm getting the same entity for two different values of current_page 
        PageRequest pageable = PageRequest.of(current_page, paginacaoSize, Sort.by("id"));


There is no duplicates Ids in database.
There is no null ids.
Doing the filter (I guess the problem is here):
        Specification<CardsKanBanEntidade> filter = Specification.where((root,query,cb)->cb.equal(root.join("kanbanLane").get("passoId"),lane_id));

        Specification<CardsKanBanEntidade> lojaFilter = Specification.where(null);
        if (lojas!=null && !lojas.isEmpty()) {
            lojaFilter = lojaFilter.and((root,query,cb)->{
                return root.get("loja").in(lojas);
            });
        }

        filter = filter.and(lojaFilter);

Above I'm filtering my Entity by a inner entity mapped by "kanbanLane":
@Entity
@Table(name="kanban__cards")
@Data
public class CardsKanBanEntidade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lane_id", referencedColumnName = "lane_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JsonBackReference
    private LanesKanBanEntidade kanbanLane;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_kanban_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JsonBackReference
    private ClientesKanBanEntidade clienteKanban;
    private String loja;//loja do cart, no db é foreign key, mas aqui nao houve a necessidade de explicitarda
    @Column(name = "card_index")
    private Integer cardIndex;//esse index é acumulativo POR LOJA nao globalmente
}

Finally fetching the data:
        Page<CardsKanBanEntidade> response = cardsKanBanRepository.findAll(filter,pageable);


My attempt was to change sorting to do it by id but I'm still facing the issue
